# Excel Count Different Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want an excel to count in a column to count how many different values. For example

1

2

3

2

3

Would give the result of 3. I was thinking something along the lines of the countif unique. This is what I have so far:

`=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(G3:G11,G3:G11)=1)*(G3:G11<>""))`

Comment: Look at [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numerical values only not including blanks:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A10,A1:A10)>0,1))
```